# How were amplitudes of the $\cos$ and $\sin$ chosen?

Tags: trigonometry

I don't understand why we use $\displaystyle\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$ in the below transformation. Can someone help to explain?

from

$$f(x)=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3}{5}e^t\left(\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)\right)$$

transform to

$$f(x)=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3}{5}\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}e^t\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}\cos(2t)+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}\sin(2t)\right)$$

let $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}=\cos\phi$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}=\sin\phi$,

$$f(x)=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3}{5}\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}e^t(\cos\phi\cos(2t)+\sin\phi\sin(2t))$$

Comment: You have the expression $1\cdot \cos 2t+ \frac 12\cdot \sin 2t$ from which $1$ and $\frac 12$ can be read off immediately. This is where they come from. Answers will explain more about why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s concentrate on the important part, which is of the form
$$
f(x)=a\cos x+b\sin x
$$
which we want to express as
$$
f(x)=A(\cos\varphi\cos x+\sin\varphi\sin x)
$$
A necessary (and sufficient) condition is that
$$
A\cos\varphi=a,\qquad A\sin\varphi=b
$$
and therefore $a^2=A^2\cos^2\varphi$, $b^2=A^2\sin^2\varphi$. Hence
$$
A^2=a^2+b^2
$$
We want $A>0$ (not necessary, but convenient), so we get
$$
A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\quad \cos\varphi=\frac{a}{A},\quad \sin\varphi=\frac{b}{A}
$$
The last two requirements can be fulfilled, because $(a/A,b/A)$ is a point on the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you :) $sin^2 +cos^2  = 1$ => $a^2 + b^2 = A^2(cos^2 +cos^2 ) = A^2$

also $\frac{b^2}{a^2}=\frac{sin^2 }{cos^2 } = tan^2  => \frac{b}{a}=tan$

Comment: @CableW The last passage is good, but writing $\varphi=\arctan(b/a)$ would be incorrect, because the arctangent only returns angles in the first and fourth quadrant. If $a<0$ you need to take $\pi+\arctan(b/a)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to normalize the vector $v=(a,b)=\left(1,\frac12\right)$ that is

$$|v|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \implies \hat v=\frac{v}{|v|}$$

has length equal to $1$ and this allows to perform the subsequent transformation for $\cos \phi$ and $\sin \phi$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that I still need to figure out the relationship between sinusoids and vector normalization. Go searching on Google now :)

Comment: @CableW You are welcome! Good work. Bye